# Class Loading in Phalcon for plugins

Tags: dependency-injection, dispatch, service-layer, phalcon

When adding a dispacher in the services.php it doesnt seem to have access to the autoloader to include class's.

Example: /config/services.php

```
$di->set('dispatcher', function() use ($di) {

   require __DIR__.'/../../app/plugins/security.php';

   $eventsManager = $di->getShared('eventsManager');

   $security = new Security($di);

   $eventsManager->attach('dispatch', $security);

   $dispatcher = new Phalcon\Mvc\Dispatcher();
   $dispatcher->setEventsManager($eventsManager);

   return $dispatcher;
});
```

Is it correct to include the require? Its the only way I can seem to have access to the security plugin? Im sure there is a better way?

Both https://github.com/phalcon/invo is different to the demonstration on the Phalcon homepage?

Anyone clarify?

Answer (score 0):

If you plan move your plugins directory to another directory there is a high possibility of breaking the application due to the static paths. An autoloader gives you the freedom to re-organize the application by just adjusting the paths on it.

The INVO application uses an autoloader:

Set a plugins directory: 
https://github.com/phalcon/invo/blob/master/public/index.php#L20

Use the class with auto-loading:
https://github.com/phalcon/invo/blob/master/public/index.php#L38

Comment: Thanks, I did this - it was my mistake I was setting the plugin directory up, but not using it in the loader.php.

Answer (score 0):

I think public/index.php is a better place for require or in the same place you can use a loader